# Python pynput not 'understanding' greek characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard, pynput

Good morning,
I am using Python's 3.8 pynput (in windows 10) to get each time the character entered (in system level) and then the unicode of this character.

```
from pynput import keyboard


def on_press(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc: #if button escape is pressed close the program
        listener.stop()
    else: #if button escape is not pressed get the unicode code of the button-char pressed
        unicode_code = ord(getattr(key, 'char', '0'))
        print("The unicode is ",unicode_code)
        print("The char entered is",chr(unicode_code))


controller = keyboard.Controller()
# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

The problem I am facing is that when I change my keyboard to greek (with shift+alt), it keeps the unicodes of the english language and not the greek ones.
You can see the screenshot attached to understand better.

[image: Screenshot]

What to do to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you aren't getting English unicode codes. You are getting unicode representation of codes returned by the keyboard. They will be the same no matter what language is chosen because keyboard layer is designed to always return same codes for same keys (by their location and/or meaning on querty/quertz or other HID compliant keyboards) if possible. What you are doing in your code is essentially reverting the process done by pynput which converts the keyboard code using char()/unichar() function. Think about it: is there a greek representation of e.g. F11 key?

I cannot remember whether pynput has higher-level inputs support or not, although I think it does. and that it should be possible to get directly what you want 
What you have to do is either to find another attribute (if there is one, I am not pynput specialist) containing the character sent to the input field, or check the current keyboard language and appropriately map the codes returned. You can also try playing with codepages using the codecs module. Worst case scenario would include snatching the character directly from the GUI's input field. But that would be very inelegant, bruteforc-ish and simply the shouldn't do it thing if not strictly necessary. There are other methods for getting input from the OS - like directly linking to its event input system or kernel using built-in libraries through ctypes, wintypes, Cocoa/Carbon on Mac or GTK on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Try using pynput version 1.1.7, it works there. It is broken after 1.4 and in between these two it works, but changing the layout with the windows shortcut while the program is running, isn't working 70% of the time, meaning Windows just doesn't change the language. Alternatively, you can work around it in newer verisons by trying [this](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/issues/226#issuecomment-624536164) solution, that converts the characters in real time if you don't care about performance.  I have opened an issue for it to be fixed in the repo's github.